# C# - LINQ ERRO "The data type text and varchar are incompatible with equal operator"

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Encontro-me com o seguinte erro ao tentar efetuar um update numa tabela:

> the data type text and varchar are incompatible with equal operator.

Já efetuei várias pesquisas e, a maioria, indicam a mesma solução: alterar o campo para `varchar(max)`. Problema: **o campo já está como varchar(30) e nem sequer é referente a um campo do tipo `Text`**

Segue o código do `update`:

```
public void updateAcaoEstado(string _stp, string _estado)
    {
        try
        {
            bo updtreg = (from bo in db.bos where (bo.bostamp == _stp && bo.ndos == 70) select bo).Single();
            updtreg.cxusername = _estado;
            updtreg.dtclose = DateTime.Today;
            this.db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Explicação dos campos:

1. bo.bostamp -> primary key - char(25)
2. dtclose -> datetime
3. cxusername -> varchar(30)

Estão todos bem mapeados no ficheiro.
Alguma ajuda?

[UPDATE]

Segue a imagem do mapeamento do campo `cxusername`

[image: Mapeamento do campo]

[UPDATE 2]

Query extraida do `profiler`

`exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[bo]
SET [dtclose] = @p36, [cxusername] = @p37
WHERE ([obrano] = @p0) AND ([boano] = @p1) AND ([ndos] = @p2) AND ([bostamp] = @p3) AND ([nmdos] = @p4) AND ([dataobra] = @p5) AND ([nome] = @p6) AND ([etotaldeb] = @p7) AND ([estab] = @p8) AND ([no] = @p9) AND ([obranome] = @p10) AND ([dataopen] = @p11) AND (NOT ([fechada] = 1)) AND ([dtclose] = @p12) AND ([site] = @p13) AND ([datafecho] = @p14) AND ([datafinal] = @p15) AND ([tabela1] = @p16) AND ([trab2] = @p17) AND ([trab1] = @p18) AND ([series] = @p19) AND ([series2] = @p20) AND ([trab4] = @p21) AND ([quarto] = @p22) AND ([trab3] = @p23) AND ([obs] = @p24) AND ([ousrinis] = @p25) AND ([ousrdata] = @p26) AND ([ousrhora] = @p27) AND ([usrinis] = @p28) AND ([usrdata] = @p29) AND ([usrhora] = @p30) AND ([cxusername] = @p31) AND ([ultfact] = @p32) AND ([vendedor] = @p33) AND ([vendnm] = @p34) AND ([segmento] = @p35)',N'@p0 decimal(10,0),
@p1 decimal(4,0),@p2 decimal(3,0),@p3 char(25),@p4 varchar(8000),@p5 datetime,@p6 char(55),@p7 decimal(19,6),@p8 decimal(3,0),@p9 decimal(10,0),@p10 varchar(8000),
@p11 datetime,@p12 datetime,@p13 varchar(8000),@p14 datetime,@p15 datetime,@p16 varchar(8000),@p17 varchar(8000),@p18 varchar(8000),@p19 varchar(8000),@p20 varchar(8000),@p21 varchar(8000),@p22 varchar(8000),@p23 varchar(8000),@p24 varchar(8000),@p25 varchar(8000),@p26 datetime,@p27 varchar(8000),@p28 varchar(8000),@p29 datetime,@p30 varchar(8000),@p31 varchar(8000),@p32 datetime,@p33 decimal(4,0),@p34 varchar(8000),@p35 varchar(8000),@p36 datetime,@p37 varchar(8000)',
@p0=6,@p1=2019,@p2=70,@p3='882a1f84-fbec-40e1-be9c-5',@p4='00-Acções CRM',@p5='2019-10-22 00:00:00',@p6='3ELEVEN LIMITED',@p7=0,@p8=0,@p9=499,@p10='',@p11='2019-10-28 00:00:00',@p12='1900-01-01 00:00:00',@p13='1834',@p14='1900-01-01 00:00:00',@p15='2019-10-30 00:00:00',@p16='Reunião',@p17='Prospecção',@p18='sdffsd',@p19='sdffsddfs',@p20='sdfsdfsdf',@p21='Roriz não tem interesse no cliente',@p22='Cliente',@p23='',@p24='',@p25='ADM',@p26='2019-10-22 00:00:00',@p27='',@p28='ADM',@p29='2019-10-22 00:00:00',@p30='',
@p31='Agendada',@p32='2019-10-31 00:00:00',@p33=22,@p34='',@p35='',@p36='2019-10-23 00:00:00',
@p37='Realizado'`

Comment: A string que está tentando gravar nocxusername é realmente menor que 30 caracteres? Você tem classe de mapeamento também correto? Poderia postar?

Comment: A string que estou a tentar gravar é "Realizado"....

Comment: Existe alguma validação no modelo?

Comment: Coloquei a imagem do mapeamento

Comment: Coloque a classe a que a propriedade cxusername pertence.

Comment: Outra coisa que me esqueci de mencionar, eu tenho um `insert` que funciona corretamente, o `update` é que não

Comment: A que classe é que se refere, `layout` ou `designer` ?

Comment: Onde está declarado `public string cxusername { get; set; }`

Comment: O `LINQ` é que trata dessa abstração, eu simplesmente faço o mapeamento consoante o que está na base de dados.. 
Ou seja, o atributo `cxusername` está inserido dentro da tabela `bo` eu apenas tenho que chamar a tabela bo, no ficheiro `Linq2SQL` (nome que eu dei), criando posteriormente a `classe` com os métodos pretendidos

Comment: Se for necessário, posso colocar aqui o código do ficheiro `dbml`.

Comment: @AdrianoMaia, você já checou a query que está sendo gerada? Conseguiria colocar na pergunta?

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann já coloquei a query extraída do `profiler`, se for útil

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann eu tenho dois atributos mapeados com varchar(max)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabei por descobrir a solução na seguinte pergunta:

[resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880416/updating-a-nvarcharmax-column-with-linq-causing-an-error)

Faltava o seguinte código num dos campos definidos como varchar(max):

`UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never`

Obrigado